# C#/Metro implementing background service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to implement service that starts on startup and monitors users acitivity only using Metro WinRT and API? I need somehow  figure out a way to get information that user started watching video. I know that it is possible to implement it in normal .NET (by kernel functions), but I would like to know whether this is possible on WinRT tablets. Maybe by creating some triggers.
Thanks

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing the new application model is designed to prevent. Not only does it violate process isolation, but it also means that over time, the user's computer will be filled with all these random services that slow the computer down.

Answer (score 0):

No, fortunately as Raymond said - it is not possible. You can monitor only applications that you create yourself with code that comes with them. Or you could create a library that does monitoring you want and ask developers of applications to use it - basically what vendors of analytics libraries would do.